# PC's programs are running but no logs in any logging

Tags: ubuntu, syslog

I have 2 remote PCs (Ubuntu 20.04) that runs 24h everyday. Apart from the `syslog`, I can also check the logs that my application writes. There is hardware connected to the PC, that communicates with my application through UDP. So through the hardware, I can also identify if my application on those PCs is alive.

Recently I have noticed that, the PCs became not reachable through the internet port. But my hardware still can receive packages, which are send via another port for UDP. Consider the PCs are not by my side, I couldn't log in and check.

After restart the PC, I notice there is no syslog in the time period, when I couldn't reach the PC. My application log of that period is also empty. But my application must have been running all the time, otherwise my hardware would inform me immediately (This point I'm 100% sure about it).

Would anyone give me some idea, what was wrong with the PC? I also attach here the  `syslog` , which covers the unreachable period.

Here `Aug 12 15:04:55` was the last output before I restart the PC.

```
Aug 12 14:30:29 x3000C kernel: [4063387.125113] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133
Aug 12 14:30:29 x3000C kernel: [4063387.125125] ata6: EH complete
Aug 12 14:31:29 x3000C systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Aug 12 14:31:29 x3000C anacron[976205]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2023-08-12
Aug 12 14:31:29 x3000C anacron[976205]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Aug 12 14:31:29 x3000C systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
Aug 12 14:39:23 x3000C systemd[1]: Starting Ubuntu Advantage Timer for running repeated jobs...
Aug 12 14:39:23 x3000C systemd[1]: ua-timer.service: Succeeded.
Aug 12 14:39:23 x3000C systemd[1]: Finished Ubuntu Advantage Timer for running repeated jobs.
Aug 12 14:39:55 x3000C snapd[155706]: autorefresh.go:589: Cannot prepare auto-refresh change due to a permanent network error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp 255.255.255.255:443: connect: network is unreachable
Aug 12 14:39:55 x3000C snapd[155706]: stateengine.go:149: state ensure error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp 255.255.255.255:443: connect: network is unreachable
Aug 12 14:41:41 x3000C ovpn-client[822626]: TLS: soft reset sec=0 bytes=26936/-1 pkts=708/0
Aug 12 14:41:41 x3000C ovpn-client[822626]: VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=ca
Aug 12 14:41:41 x3000C ovpn-client[822626]: VERIFY KU OK
Aug 12 14:41:41 x3000C ovpn-client[822626]: Validating certificate extended key usage
Aug 12 14:41:41 x3000C ovpn-client[822626]: ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
Aug 12 14:41:41 x3000C ovpn-client[822626]: VERIFY EKU OK
Aug 12 14:41:41 x3000C ovpn-client[822626]: VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=server_2023
Aug 12 14:41:41 x3000C ovpn-client[822626]: Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Aug 12 14:41:41 x3000C ovpn-client[822626]: Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Aug 12 14:41:41 x3000C ovpn-client[822626]: Control Channel: TLSv1.3, cipher TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
Aug 12 15:04:55 x3000C snapd[155706]: autorefresh.go:589: Cannot prepare auto-refresh change due to a permanent network error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp 255.255.255.255:443: connect: network is unreachable
Aug 12 15:04:55 x3000C snapd[155706]: stateengine.go:149: state ensure error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp 255.255.255.255:443: connect: network is unreachable
Aug 17 13:55:01 x3000C systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Aug 17 13:55:01 x3000C systemd[1]: Activated swap /swapfile.
Aug 17 13:55:01 x3000C systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
Aug 17 13:55:01 x3000C systemd-modules-load[391]: Inserted module 'lp'
Aug 17 13:55:01 x3000C systemd-modules-load[391]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Aug 17 13:55:01 x3000C systemd-modules-load[391]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Aug 17 13:55:01 x3000C systemd[1]: Finished Create System Users.
Aug 17 13:55:01 x3000C systemd-modules-load[391]: Inserted module 'msr'
Aug 17 13:55:01 x3000C systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
Aug 17 13:55:01 x3000C systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Modules.
Aug 17 13:55:01 x3000C systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
Aug 17 13:55:01 x3000C systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Configuration File System...
```

Here are the loggings from the other PC, `Jul 25 12:17:01` was the last output in `syslog`:

```
Jul 25 10:56:20 x3000C ovpn-client[1160251]: ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
Jul 25 10:56:20 x3000C ovpn-client[1160251]: VERIFY EKU OK
Jul 25 10:56:20 x3000C ovpn-client[1160251]: VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=server_2023
Jul 25 10:56:20 x3000C ovpn-client[1160251]: Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Jul 25 10:56:20 x3000C ovpn-client[1160251]: Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Jul 25 10:56:20 x3000C ovpn-client[1160251]: Control Channel: TLSv1.3, cipher TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
Jul 25 11:06:44 x3000C whoopsie[1094]: [11:06:44] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jul 25 11:06:44 x3000C whoopsie[1094]: [11:06:44] offline
Jul 25 11:06:44 x3000C whoopsie[1094]: [11:06:44] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jul 25 11:06:45 x3000C whoopsie[1094]: [11:06:45] online
Jul 25 11:17:01 x3000C CRON[1275476]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 25 11:30:01 x3000C CRON[1275603]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
Jul 25 11:33:02 x3000C systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Jul 25 11:33:02 x3000C anacron[1275629]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2023-07-25
Jul 25 11:33:02 x3000C anacron[1275629]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Jul 25 11:33:02 x3000C systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
Jul 25 11:56:20 x3000C ovpn-client[1160251]: TLS: soft reset sec=0 bytes=30904/-1 pkts=740/0
Jul 25 11:56:20 x3000C ovpn-client[1160251]: VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=ca
Jul 25 11:56:20 x3000C ovpn-client[1160251]: VERIFY KU OK
Jul 25 11:56:20 x3000C ovpn-client[1160251]: Validating certificate extended key usage
Jul 25 11:56:20 x3000C ovpn-client[1160251]: ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
Jul 25 11:56:20 x3000C ovpn-client[1160251]: VERIFY EKU OK
Jul 25 11:56:20 x3000C ovpn-client[1160251]: VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=server_2023
Jul 25 11:56:20 x3000C ovpn-client[1160251]: Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Jul 25 11:56:20 x3000C ovpn-client[1160251]: Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Jul 25 11:56:20 x3000C ovpn-client[1160251]: Control Channel: TLSv1.3, cipher TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
Jul 25 12:17:01 x3000C CRON[1276046]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 31 12:00:56 x3000C systemd-modules-load[390]: Inserted module 'lp'
Jul 31 12:00:56 x3000C systemd-modules-load[390]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Jul 31 12:00:56 x3000C systemd-modules-load[390]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Jul 31 12:00:56 x3000C systemd-modules-load[390]: Inserted module 'msr'
Jul 31 12:00:56 x3000C systemd-sysctl[402]: Not setting net/ipv4/conf/all/promote_secondaries (explicit setting exists).
Jul 31 12:00:56 x3000C systemd-sysctl[402]: Not setting net/ipv4/conf/default/promote_secondaries (explicit setting exists).
Jul 31 12:00:56 x3000C systemd[1]: Finished Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Jul 31 12:00:56 x3000C systemd[1]: Activating swap /swapfile...
Jul 31 12:00:56 x3000C systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
Jul 31 12:00:56 x3000C systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Jul 31 12:00:56 x3000C systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Platform Persistent Storage Archival being skipped.
Jul 31 12:00:56 x3000C systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
Jul 31 12:00:56 x3000C systemd[1]: Starting Create System Users...
```